# Initializing a readonly property

Tags: objective-c

I was trying to create a property which is readonly. I wanted to initialize with a value from the class creating an instance of this class, e.g.

`@property (retain,readonly) NSString *firstName;`

And I tried to initialize it like this:

`-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)n{
self.firstName = n;
}`

Once I did this, the compiler reported an error that the readonly property cannot be assigned. So how can i do this ?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Either assign to the instance variable directly (don't forget to add a `retain` or `copy` if you need it) or redeclare the property in a private class extension. Like this:

In your .h file:

```
@property (readonly, copy) NSString *firstName;
```

In your .m file:

```
@interface MyClass ()

// Redeclare property as readwrite
@property (readwrite, copy) NSString *firstName;

@end


@implementation MyClass

@synthesize firstName;
...
```

Now you can use the synthesized setter in your implementation but the class interface still shows the property as readonly. Note that other classes that import your .h file can still call `-[MyClass setFirstName:]` but they won't know that it exists and will get a compiler warning.

Comment: Is there any advantage to using the synthesized setter vs. the approach suggested by @Renger?

Answer (score 14):

Don't use the synthesized setter:

```
firstName = [n retain]; //Or copy
```

It is generally advised to bypass the setters in any init and dealloc methods anyway.

Comment: The problem with my above implementation is that the value is not retained. Once i add the retain to the property, will this assignment set the value into property. And if some other object accesses this property will this value be there. I have also modified my question

Comment: Why would this be a problem? Using `firstname = [n retain]` will just make firstName a pointer to `n`. So yeah, when some other object accesses this property, the value will be there. :)

Comment: If I try to do it this way if I access this property, i am getting the following exception.Program received signal: “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”. And this error is not due to any other property. I investigated this a lot in debugger. This property shows "out of scope". And if I assign it with ,<code>self.firstName = n;</code>. then everything works fine.

Comment: Ok, that is very weird. Using `firstname = [n retain]` just works for me. Anyway, if Ole Begemann's method work I guess thats fine.

Comment: I was trying it without invoking the retain on n.  After using this <code>firstname = [n retain]</code> it works perfectly fine.
 As far as i understand if we do a direct assignment the reference count remains the same (since we are skipping the @property setter)and we have to do it explicitly, increase the reference count.  Thanks, this seems to be a perfect solution. Can you please edit your main answer, that would be great.

Comment: That's wrong. You can't generally access (synthesized) properties like that.

Comment: Why not? It's no different than a 'regular' ivar.

Answer (score 7):

You can directly access the property with:

`_firstName = n;`

The setter method that `self.firstName = n` implies will not be synthesized because you specified `readonly` in `@property (retain,readonly) NSString *firstName;`, hence the compiler error.

Comment: it is my understanding that _firstName will exist. It is the underlying ivar created when the property is declared. As of Xcode 4.6 the compiler should automatically create this for you.

Comment: That is my understanding too @Bob9630. The other answers to this question did not produce the desired result in my case, while this did.

Comment: Don't prefix `_firstName` with `self.`.